# Single data with multiple files to show on blade.php

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-6

I want to show the message of the user with his name, date, message and with multiple files in Laravel 6.

```
Admin 2nd Oct 2019
this is my message.
file1, file2 ,file3,....
```

This is how I want to show data

This is my controller code:

```
$data2=DB::table('order_deliver')
    -> select('order_deliver.id' , 'order_deliver.deliver_by_id' , 'order_deliver.message' , 'order_deliver.created_at','order_deliver_attechments.attechment','order_deliver_attechments.deliver_id')
    -> join('order_deliver_attechments','order_deliver_attechments.deliver_id','=','order_deliver.id')
    -> where(['order_deliver.order_id' => $order_id])
    //->->distinct()
    //->groupBy('order_deliver_attechments.deliver_id')
    -> get()->toArray();


  return view("Admin.view.AdminViewSingleOrder" , ['adminMessage'=>$data2]);
```

blade.php code

```
@foreach($adminMessage as $info)
             <div class="pdl-20">
               <h4 class="text-capitalize "><i class="fa fa-user pdr-10 fs-19" aria-hidden="true"></i> <b>Admin</b><span class="fs-10 pdl-10">{{$info->created_at}} 16 nov, 2019</span></h4>
               <p><i class="fa fa-comments-o pdr-10 fs-19" aria-hidden="true"></i>{{$info->message}}</p>
               <p><i class="fa fa-paperclip pdr-10 fs-19" aria-hidden="true"></i> <span class="font-weight-normal text-capitalize ">
                <a href="{{--URL::to('/Orders_attachments/'.$info->attechment)--}}" download>{{$info->attechment}}, </a></span><p>
             </div>
             @endforeach
```

I am getting the data but the only problem is that as there are multiple files so the other information is also repeated along with files which I don't want.

This is my output result

[image]

Comment: What have you attempted so far? Can you share some of the code?

Comment: We don't know what you are trying to do, so please explain your issues clearly. Nobody can answer your question at the current state it is in.

Comment: I added all the information in my question

Comment: Thank you for editing your question, that is in a much better state now. However, I have had to do significant reformatting to make it readable - if you could take the time to practice with the code formatting tools, it will help you ask a readable question on the first go. In turn, that is much more likely to get upvoted, which will get more readers looking at your question.

Comment: You need to now either change your query to get the array in different format or you can use collection group to to group data by user id and run for each loop.

Answer (score 0):

You can define the relationship between your model like following assuming that you have `OrderDeliver` and `OrderDeliverAttechment` model. Check the foreign key name if they are different.

```
class OrderDeliver extends Model
{
    /**
     * Get the OrderDeliverAttechments for the OrderDeliver.
     */
    public function attachments()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(OrderDeliverAttechment::class);
    }
}
```

Now you can use eloquent to run your query like following

```
$orderDelivers = OrderDeliver::where('order_id',$order_id)->with('attachments')->get();
```

Now you will have your resulting collection a Multidimensional array and you can run 2 nested foreach loop and display data appropriately

```
@foreach($orderDelivers as $orderDeliver)

    //Display data from main table
    @foreach($orderDeliver->attachments as $attachments)
        //Display fields from order_deliver_attachment table
    @endforeach

@endforeach
```

Comment: i need 1 more help ....i got the result in dd() but when i put it on the blade.php file it is not showing the files but other data is shown

Comment: Add your screenshot of the dd() output and blade code you are using.